# Routing issue after adding Areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

i used [Afana solution](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) to build a multi language website.

i did some changes to add culture to URL for some SEO purpose.

now i have a BaseController like below and every controller dervied from this controller.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        string cultureName = RouteData.Values["culture"] as string;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cultureName))
        {
            HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["_culture_"];
            if (cultureCookie != null)
                cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
            else
                cultureName = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture();
        }

        cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName);

        if (RouteData.Values["culture"] as string != cultureName)
        {
            RouteData.Values["culture"] = cultureName.ToLowerInvariant();
            Response.RedirectToRoute(RouteData.Values);
        }

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;


        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }
}
```

and this is routes config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "WithCulture",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture = String.Empty, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { culture = "[a-z]{2}" }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture = String.Empty, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

It (seems) work well. i mean i redirected from this links:

```
/
/Home
```

to this:

```
/fr
/fr/Home
```

but when i add an Area (for example Manager).
at this point i get errors for some URLs. for example:

```
/
/Home/
```

redirected to this URL

```
/Manager/Home?culture=en
```

what i missed?

Comment: Have you tried adding `namaspaces` parameter to `MapRoute` method? For example, `namespaces: new[] { "someNamespace.Controllers" }`

Comment: i added namespaces parameter but same problem.

Comment: Have you also added it inside `...AreaRegistration`?

Comment: yes i did.  `namespaces: new[] { "something.Areas.Manager.Controllers" }`